# getResourceAsStream() can't find file

Tags: java, file, inputstream, snakeyaml

I'm trying to open a YAML file using the InputStream to use on SnakeYAML.
Though I have encountered a problem, the file is always being null, no matter what I tried, here is my code:

```
this.configFile = new File("config.yml");
this.yaml = new Yaml();

if (!configFile.exists()) {
    try {
        configFile.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

InputStream inputStream = this.getClass()
        .getClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream(configFile.getName());

Map<String, Object> obj = yaml.load(inputStream);
System.out.println(obj);
```

I've tried to directly type "config.yml" instead of "configFile.getName()" I even tried `System.getProperty("user.dir") + configFile.getName()` but it always returns null and gives the error `org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed`.

I am sure the file exists as I can see it and edit and it is in the project folder, I just can't seem to be able to access it.
[image][image]

Comment: have you tried complete path?

Comment: @Deadpool Yeah, unfortunately didn't work either.

Comment: You're trying to load it as a resource - is it available within the classpath? Is there any reason you're not using a `FileInputStream`?

Comment: @JonSkeet The reason was just because I was following thishttps://www.baeldung.com/java-snake-yaml.

Comment: @JonSkeet But well, it worked as soon as I swapped to `FileInputStream`, thank you!

Comment: It is not `InputStream` but `getResourceAsStream()` that can't find the file. Be accurate. And all the stuff about `exists()/createNewFile()` is just a waste of time. Either the resource is present or it isn't, which isn't a runtime condition, it is a matter of whether you packaged your JAR file correctly: so a simple test for `null` would suffice.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a `'/'` for specifying the correct path when using `System.getProperty("user.dir")`.

So, maybe you have to write

`System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + configFile.getName()`.

Comment: `user.dir` has nothing to do with it. OP Is loading it as a resource.

Answer (score -1):

In case YAML file is a resource and in classPath you can use 'getClassLoader':

```
public KafkaConfig getKafkaConfigCl() throws IOException {
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass()
            .getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("application.yaml");
    return yaml.loadAs(inputStream, KafkaConfig.class);
}
```

But, when file is out of classPath use 'FileInputStream':

```
public KafkaConfig getKafkaConfig() throws IOException {
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
    File file = new File(yamlFilePath);
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    return yaml.loadAs(inputStream, KafkaConfig.class);
}
```

Comment: OP is already using `getClassLoader()`. Read the question.